# Erro Instalando WebLogic Oracle

Tags: oracle

Estou tentando instalar o Oracle WebLogic, mais no processo de instalação aparece a mensagem:

> C:>java -jar fmw_12.2.1.0.0_infrastructure.jar
>   O arquivo de log do acionador é C:\Users\Wagner\AppData\Local\Temp\OraInstall2017-04-06_04-30-36PM\launcher2017-04-06_04-30-36PM.log.
>   Extraindo arquivos................................
>   Este instalador deve ser executado usando o Java Development Kit (JDK),
>   porém C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121 não é um JDK válido.

Pressione qualquer tecla para sair...